# Magento Product Import - Beyond CSV/XLS

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.4

I want to move an entire catalog from one magento store to another store on another server.  I realize I can import via csv, but I also want to maintain product relationships, grouped product relationship, config product relationships and images.  The only way I can think to do this is to write my own script using the Magento API.   Is there another more straight forward way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this extension, we'll see if it does the job:

http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-product-import-export.html

Comment: I have used that extension, purchased a couple years ago. It was very good except 1.) very slow (about 1 product per second) because it uses the old magento import method (new method is more like 100+ per second). 2.) Still had lots of problems getting image import to work right. There is a free extension by AMartinez that works really well (full speed 100+ per second), but still has problems with images and slightly lags the comerceextensions import script in terms of data that can be imported.

Answer (score 0):

Export the DB directly and you would retain all this information. This would also be significantly faster for large sets of objects.

If that feels too dirty, your API solution will contain all the data, but will take longer to import/export.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that, but I'm afraid it will conflict with the data in the existing database.  This is going to into a magento site that already exists.